# How to display the axis to the right?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have 3 axes (velue-axis)

Can one axis be displayed on the left

Other two axes to display on the right?

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/multiple-axes
(In this example, the axis is located on the right, but I do not know how to configure it)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Granted this isn't entirely clear when you first look at the demo. The important thing to look at is this section:

```
 categoryAxis: {
                 categories: [], 
                 axisCrossingValues:[]//This is the fella you are looking for. 
               }
```

I have tweaked the demo slightly to show you one of the axis in the middle of the chart. http://dojo.telerik.com/ASidu

The number is simply the position `column` on the chart that the axis should be rendered. By default if this in't set then all axis should be on the left hand side as normal. but if we start applying a number greater than 0 then the axis will shift. So in the example we have 3 value axis set up:

```
 valueAxes: [{
                    name: "rain",
                    color: "#007eff",
                    min: 0,
                    max: 60
                }, {
                    name: "wind",
                    color: "#73c100",
                    min: 0,
                    max: 60
                }, {
                    name: "temp",
                    min: -30,
                    max: 30
                }],
```

so if we look at them from crossing the y-axis (i.e. the bottom axis) we have 31 columns available to us `1- 31` so in my tweak I have applied this to the crossingAxis:

```
axisCrossingValues: [32, 15, 0]
```

This is effectively telling each of the value axes where they should be positioned:

so:

- "rain" should be at position 32
- "wind" should be at position 15
- "temp" should be at position 0

So the order in which you add your value axes will determine which setting they take based on the order you include them.

Hopefully that helps clear things up for you. If you need any more info let me know and I will update accordingly